# $x_{n+2} = 5x_{n+1} + 6x_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the solution of the above, $x_1=1, x_2=41$. I got this far:
$$x_{n+2} + x_{n+1} = 6(x_{n+1} + x_{n})$$
$$y_n = x_{n+1} + x_n$$
$$y_{n+1} = 6y_n$$
This being a geometric series:
$$y_n = y_1 \cdot 6^{n-1}$$
$$x_{n+1} + x_n = 42 \cdot 6^{n-1} = 7 \cdot 6^n $$

This is where i'm currently stuck.

Comment: hint: let $z^n:=x_n$.

Comment: Now put $z_n=x_{n+1}-6x_n$. Then solve a simple linear system of two equations.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic equation gives $$r^2-5r-6=0 \implies (r-6)(r+1)=0 \implies x_n = c_1 6^n + c_2 (-1)^n$$

Using the initial conditions we get

$$x_1=1=6c_1-c_2 \land x_2 = 41 = 36c_1 +c_1$$
Add the two equations together and you get
$$42 = 42c_1 \implies c_1=1 $$
Then use that to get that $$1=6-c_2 \implies c_2 = 5$$
So your final solution should be

$$x_n = 6^n + 5(-1)^n$$